# Microsoft Report Viewer ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datatable, reportviewer

This is my first time using the Microsoft Report Viewer control and I'm thinking it is very straight forward but I keep getting this following error:

```
 An error occurred during local report processing.
 The report definition for report 'Report3' has not been specified
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have a view from my Oracle Database that I am using that looks like this:

[image: DataTable View]

I walk through the GUI and make a "New Report" and add this DataSet to a "Table".  I used the Query Builder to create the "FillByModel" and "GetDataByModel" functions and it all returns the correct data from the database but when I run the page that I have the ReportViewer control on, it gives me the above error.  I have no idea what that error means and after Googling the crap out of it and trying everything I have no idea how to resolve it.

Here is the .aspx code for my ReportViewer object:

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="Paint_Reporting.Report3.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="LOL" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="PaintModelNumberDetailTableAdapters.PAINT_MODELNUMBERDETAILLISTINGTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Could someone help me figure out this error?

Comment: do you have Paint_Reporting.Report3.rdlc file prepared?

Comment: Yes, it is in my Solution.  "Report3.rdlc"

Comment: Did you solve it? If not, post another question with the other error mentioning this one...

Answer (score 2):

You must call this in your code behind:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "CommonLayer.Reports.SalesByPrice.rdlc";
```

Just make sure to change the names accordingly, that is, set `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath` property to the path of the `RDL` file.

Here's a complete discussion detailing the options your have to workaround this problem:

[The report definition for report 'xxx' has not been specified](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/5b6cd9bf-baf0-4726-8507-5e732c48dd10)

Comment: Should I be doing that on my Page_Load()?  I'll try it out and see what happens.

Comment: An error occurred during local report processing.
The report definition for report 'CommonLayer.Reports.Report3' has not been specified
Could not find file 'C:\Projects\Paint Reporting\Paint Reporting\CommonLayer.Reports.Report2.rdlc'.

Comment: See that the namespace must match or else it will fail. You mention Report3 and then the error contains Report2. Something is wrong with that naming... CommonLayer: your report is inside this namespace? I don't think so.

Comment: It should all be Report3, I've just been making and deleting so many temp reports trying to get this thing working I'm trying to keep it understandable for StackOverflow question-answerers.  :)

Comment: I'm going to delete all my temp reports and start again.

Comment: Adding the report path to my code behind worked, now I am receiving the following:

An error has occurred during report processing.
Cannot create a connection to data source 'PaintModelNumberDetail'.
The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not be found.

Comment: This error is because you specified this in the HTML markup: `TypeName="PaintModelNumberDetailTableAdapters.PAINT_MODELNUMBERDETAILLISTINGTableAdapter"` Do you have this type in your project?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17820/discussion-between-se-brandon-and-leniel-macaferi)

Answer (score 0):

you also can add the exact path of your .rdlc

example mine it work to me:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\miuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\miproyect\SSHD\Views\Summary\Report1.rdlc";
```